# Rails ActionCable broadcast not working from Controller but works from console

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I am using Rails 7.0.5 and testing the Action Cable feature to send broadcast message using controller action. The broadcast as below works from rails console, but same if I put in controller action, the broadcast displays for 2-3 seconds on index page and then disappears.

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "chat_channel", {title: 'Hello From Rails'}
```

Below is my channel JS file:

```
received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    document.getElementById("my").innerHTML = data.title;
  }
```

Below is my index page where data needs to be displayed(broadcasted):

```
<div id="my">
</div>
```

Below is my controller file

```
class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def index
      ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_channel", { title: "Hello From Rails" })
      end
   end
```

Below is the subscription file

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     stream_from "chat_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be a timing issue with your broadcast call from the controller. One possible reason why the broadcast message disappears after a few seconds on the index page is that the page is reloading or refreshing, causing the WebSocket connection to be closed.

To ensure that the broadcast message is received and displayed on the index page, you can try the following:

1. Modify the controller action to render a view instead of redirecting:

   ```
   class HelloController < ApplicationController
    def index
     ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_channel", { title: "Hello From Rails" })
     render "index"
    end
   end
   ```
2. Make sure that the channel is correctly subscribed and the `received` callback is defined in your JavaScript:

   ```
   // app/assets/javascripts/channels/chat.js
   import consumer from "./consumer"

   consumer.subscriptions.create("ChatChannel", {
    connected() {
     // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    },

    disconnected() {
     // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
    },

    received(data) {
     // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
     document.getElementById("my").innerHTML = data.title;
    },
   });
   ```

Make sure the JavaScript file is included in your layout or the specific view where the `#my` element is present.

With these changes, the broadcast message should be sent from the controller action and received by the subscribed clients connected to the `ChatChannel`, updating the `#my` element on the index page.

Comment: This is not a separate JS file but its a JS file which is included in the app/javascript/channels folder. Doesn't Rails 7 automatically compiles whatever JS files are under above path and show them in the views? 

Please note that in the above JS file, If a put an example JS code in the `connected()`, it displays fine which means the JS file is being picked up for showing in views. 

The issue is that the JS code from the `received(data)` section is not being picked up in views.